# Using multiple conditions in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have been searching online and even amongst Stackoverflow questions about this issue but couldnt receive any related response. 
The SQL query that I have shown below,

```
SELECT Scania.GensetType
    , Scania.EngineType
    , Scania.Engine60Hz
    , Scania.Alternator
    , Scania.PriceEur 
FROM Scania 
LEFT JOIN NordhavnGenset 
    ON Scania.GensetType=NordhavnGenset.Alternator 
WHERE (NordhavnGenset.MaxKva='46') 
    and (Generator.Alternator='ECP34-1LN/4') 
    and (insulation.Insulation='F (90ºC/45ºC)') 
    and (Klasse.Klasse='KRS\r') 
    and (airinletfilter.AirInletFilter='No') 
    and (Ip.IP='IP23');
```

Always returns the error message below, and I have checked several times that this column exists in the table!

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'Generator.Alternator' in 'where clause'
```

However if I execute the query by stopping at the first Where clause, then the results are displayed,

```
SELECT Scania.GensetType
    , Scania.EngineType
    , Scania.Engine60Hz
    , Scania.Alternator
    , Scania.PriceEur 
FROM Scania 
LEFT JOIN NordhavnGenset 
    ON Scania.GensetType=NordhavnGenset.Alternator 
WHERE (NordhavnGenset.MaxKva='46');
```

The new query

```
    SELECT  Scania.GensetType, Scania.EngineType, Scania.Engine60Hz, Scania.Alternator, Scania.PriceEur
FROM Scania  
LEFT JOIN NordhavnGenset
    ON Scania.GensetType=NordhavnGenset.Alternator 
LEFT JOIN Generator
    ON Scania.Alternator=Generator.Alternator
LEFT JOIN Insulation 
    ON NordhavnGenset.Insulation=Insulation.Insulation
LEFT JOIN Klasse
    ON NordhavnGenset.Class=Klasse.Class
LEFT JOIN AirInletFilter
    ON NordhavnGenset.AirInletFilter=AirInletFilter.AirInletFilter
LEFT JOIN IP
    ON NordhavnGenset.Ip=IP.IP
WHERE (NordhavnGenset.MaxKva='46') and (Generator.Alternator='ECP34-1LN/4') and (Insulation.Insulation='F (90ºC/45ºC)') and (Klasse.Klasse='KRS\r') and (AirInletFilter.AirInletFilter='No') and (IP.IP='IP23');
```

Comment: if you give your answer mark that solution as accept!plz.

Answer (score 7):

It does not appear that you are Joining on a table called `Generator`.  You cannot have the table in your `WHERE` clause unless you `JOIN` on it.

If you add a `JOIN` to `Generator` then you can use it in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Scania 
LEFT JOIN NordhavnGenset 
    ON Scania.GensetType=NordhavnGenset.Alternator 
LEFT JOIN Generator 
    ON ....
WHERE (Generator.Alternator='ECP34-1LN/4') ...
```

You also have other tables in your `WHERE` clause that are not `JOINed` on, so you will need to add those as well.

Comment: +1 - The where clause also references a whole bunch of other tables not present in the query.

Comment: @hatchet I saw that as well.  I added that to my answer.

Comment: Yes I added it as you said, however it says Unknown Column Scania.Alternator in "ON Clause"

Comment: @Yoosuf you have to be sure that the fields you are joining on are included in the tables you have added to the query. You cannot reference fields that are not available

Comment: @Yoosuf - Every field that you reference in your query ***must*** come from a *table* that you reference in your *joins*.  In this case you seem to be saying that you want to use the field `Alternator` from the table `Generator`.  This means that you ***must*** include the `Generator` table in your joins.  And that goes for every table you use anywhere in your query.

Comment: Yes I am sure that its all mentioned. Because initially I received an error NO UNIQUE TABLE ALIAS. Thereafter I made a variable and called it. After making that variable only I received this error
SELECT  Scania.GensetType, Scania.EngineType, Scania.Engine60Hz, Scania.Alternator, Scania.PriceEur
FROM Scania t, NordhavnGenset 
LEFT JOIN NordhavnGenset v
    ON t.GensetType=v.Alternator 
LEFT JOIN Generator
    ON Scania.Alternator=Generator.Alternator

Comment: @Yoosuf since you have created a table alias, for Scania did you try ON t.Alternator=Generator.Alternator?

Comment: Yes but it didnt work. Anyhow I rectified it by removing the second table from the FROM clause. However I receive this error "#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf16_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' "

Comment: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf16_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: @Yoosuf are the data types the same on all fields you are `JOINing` on?  If not, then you will need to perform a `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

Comment: yes except Scania.alternator all others are utf8 (only this is UTF 16)

Comment: @Yoosuf what is the datatype on both of those fields?

Comment: ON Scania.Alternator=Generator.Alternator
Both are text but first is UTF16 next is UTF8

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12707/discussion-between-yoosuf-and-bluefeet)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you are not joining the tables that you are using in the `WHERE` clause.

The following would always give an error -

```
and (Generator.Alternator='ECP34-1LN/4') 
and (insulation.Insulation='F (90ºC/45ºC)') 
and (Klasse.Klasse='KRS\r') 
and (airinletfilter.AirInletFilter='No') 
and (Ip.IP='IP23');
```

You either need to have the table joined or the alias of the table should be the name before the '.'.

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the `Generator` table in the join. Either add it, or you may mean `NordhavnGenset.Alternator` instead of `Generator.Alternator`